# How to find position where a list is sorted up to using loops?

Tags: python, sorting

For example, `[4,5,6,1,2,3]` should return `2` since the list is sorted up to the 2nd position.

Comment: what you have tried by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If the list is sorted every value will always be greater or equal to the one the precedes it, so you don't need loop**s**; a single loop will work. So you can `zip()` the list with itself to compare adjacent values. Use `enumerate()` to get the index and catch the exception when the list is actually sorted:

```
l = [4,5,6,1,2,3] 

try:
    print(next(i for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(l, l[1:])) if a > b))
except StopIteration:
    print("list is sorted")    

# prints 2
```

You can alternatively pass a default to `next()` instead of the `try/catch`. So if your list is already sorted and you want `-1` in that case:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

next((i for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(l, l[1:])) if a > b), -1)
# -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier to digest implementation would be like this:

Enumerate the list, and at every index, check if the next number is smaller, and return the index if so. Since we can't check the next index when the current index is at the end, stop at the second last element.

```
l = [4,5,6,1,2,3] 
l2 = [4,5,6,7,8,3] 

def get_unsorted_index(input_list):
  for index, value in enumerate(input_list[:-1]):
     if input_list[index+1] < value:
         return index
  return len(input_list)-1
  
print(get_unsorted_index(l))
print(get_unsorted_index(l2))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think it would make more sense to return `index + 1` rather than `index` in the loop, and `len(input_list)` rather than `-1` after the loop.

Comment: Good point about len(input_list), but isn't index (e.g. 2) what they asked for? index 2 is 6, which is the latest position that is still sorted

Comment: Well, your function is called `get_unsorted_index`, so most people reading its name and using it would expect it to return the index of the first unsorted element, not the number of sorted elements. The way your function currently works, I would call it `get_length_sorted_prefix` or something similar, since the index of the last sorted element is equal to the number of sorted elements.

Answer (score 0):

If list is sorted if the following entry is bigger than the current entry. Thus you can look at the differences between following entries to find the argument of the last-ordered index in the array. First, make two lists as follows:

```
l = [4,5,6,1,2,3]
temp1 = l[1:]
temp2 = l[0:-1]
```

Then we can compute the difference in a 1-line for loop:

```
diff = [temp1[ii] - temp2[ii] for ii in range(len(temp1))]  # [1, 1, -5, 1, 1]
```

Now we need to find the first number in `diff` which is smaller than 0.

```
try:
    solution = [diff[ii] < 0 for ii in range(len(diff))].index(True)
except ValueError:
    solution = len(l)
```

Where the `try` and `except` is set to catch a case where the array is sorted entirely